# How can I see what method I'm in, in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio-4.1

It used to be (up through Android Studio 4.1, IIRC) that when editing a file, you could see the name of the method (and/or class, etc.) that the cursor is in, displayed in the status bar near the line / column number. This was very helpful when the beginning of the method was away off the top of the screen somewhere, so that you didn't have to scroll up a page or two to find it, lose your place, and then scroll back down.

Now, in Android Studio 4.2, I don't see this. I still see the column / line number in the status bar (displayed in the lower right), and if you right click there, you can toggle the display of several items. But the name of the current method isn't one of the options.

I've tried the Structure pane, and while it does list the methods in the class I'm editing, it doesn't indicate the current method. (Nor do I want to allocate so much real estate just to see a method name, if I don't have to.)

I also tried searching Android Studio help, to no avail. Has this feature disappeared? If not, where can I find it again?

Answer (score 12):

Showing current place in code can be achieved using [navigation bar](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro#the_user_interface) or breadcrumbs.

To turn on breacrumbs go to Android Studio `Settings / Editor / General / Breadcrumbs`. Make sure this feature is activated for your programming language.

[image: breadcrumbs setting]

[image: breacrumbs]

Answer (score 2):

I found it. There's a navigation bar near the top of the screen (see #2 in the [diagram here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro?utm_source=android-studio#the_user_interface)) that shows the current context, down to the current method or whatever the cursor is in. Maybe this moved from the bottom part of the screen, I don't know.

Comment: Just upgraded and needed this. Thanks for posting your answer!!